# connect python to Hive

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I want to connect hive from the python.
for testing purpose I created below script in Pycharm and try to connect the hive

```
from pyhive import  hive
import sys
import pandas as pd
import ssl
import thrift_sasl
con=hive.Connection(host="ip_addrs",port=10000,username="hiveuser_test", auth='NOSASL')
cursor = con.cursor()
print(cursor.fetchall())
print(con)
```

while running the code getting the below error:

```
C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/username_dim/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username_dim/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Test", line 11, in <module>
    con=hive.Connection(host="ip_addres",port=10000,username="hiveuser_test", auth='NOSASL')
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 198, in __init__
    response = self._client.OpenSession(open_session_req)
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\TCLIService\TCLIService.py", line 187, in OpenSession
    return self.recv_OpenSession()
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\TCLIService\TCLIService.py", line 199, in recv_OpenSession
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\thrift\protocol\TBinaryProtocol.py", line 148, in readMessageBegin
    name = self.trans.readAll(sz)
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 162, in read
    self.__rbuf = BufferIO(self.__trans.read(max(sz, self.__rbuf_size)))
  File "C:\Users\username_dim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TSocket.py", line 132, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
Process finished with exit code 1
Core-site.xml
```

I used to configure hiveserver2

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.sqoop2.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.sqoop2.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
 </property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hiveuser_test.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
 </property>
<property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hiveuser_test.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.hosts</name>
     <value>*</value>
</property>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
  </property

> Blockquote
```

Could you please help me to rectify the error

Comment: trying using import pyhs2 getting below error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudera'

Answer (score 2):

cursor.execute("SELECT....") is missing. That's why your thrift connection is not able to read any data `thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes`

The modified code is below.

```
from pyhive import  hive
import sys
import pandas as pd
import ssl
import thrift_sasl
con=hive.Connection(host="ip_addrs",port=10000,username="hiveuser_test", auth='NOSASL')
cursor = con.cursor()
select_stmt = 'SELECT * FROM t1 LIMIT 10'
cursor.execute(select_stmt)
print(cursor.fetchall())
print(con)
```

Note: Replace the this line as per your need. select_stmt = 'SELECT * FROM t1 LIMIT 10'

Comment: Sold Problem :) Thanks for support